# Authorization headers with Retrofit + Robospice + Jackson

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit, robospice

I am creating app that consumes REST Api. My API has ability to login/logout in order to access private data. I am creating consumer(client Android app) with Retrofit + Robospice + Jackson.
Everything was okey, but than authorization part came into play.
I need to provide token and other credentials in my request `Authorization Header`.
This can be easily done by using `RequestInterceptor`. Here is complete tutorial how to use basic Authentication.
 [Basic Authentication with Retrofit](https://futurestud.io/blog/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit/) .
It is clear how to implement this. But in my case I also have resources that can be accessed without credentials.

Here is part of my API declared with Retrofit Annotations

```
public interface MalibuRestApi {
    //Doesn't need credentials
    @GET("/store/categories")
    Category.List categoryList();
    //Doesn't need credentials
    @GET("/store/categories/{id}/products")
    Product.List productList(@Path("id")int categoryId);
    // Needs credentials
    @POST("/store/users/{id}/logout")
       // Needs credentials
    User logout(@Path("id") int id,@Body Credentials userCredentials);
       // Needs credentials !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    @POST("/store/users/{id}/orders/")
    void makeAnOrder(@Path("id") int userId,@Body Order order,Callback<Void> callback);


}
```

Please have a look on  `makeAnOrder` method. It uses POST body to pass details about order. So combining credentials and order seems horrible and not efficient, and I won't use it under no circumstances.

It is possible to use interceptor.

```
  builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    if 
                    String token = .... // getting token.
                    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    request.addHeader("Authorization",token);
                }
            });
```

I can filter requests and add Auth headers where I need them according to request URL, but ......
According to the discussion [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/486).
**@JakeWharton**

> The relative URL is not exposed in the request interceptor because it
>   may not be fully resolved yet. A request interceptor has the ability
>   to perform path replacements and append query parameter

There is one possible workaround.
**@powerje**

> I'm not sure how to access the relative URL in RequestInterceptor but
>   the solution I used in a similar situation was to check my UserManager
>   (a global which manages the currently logged in user) to see if a user
>   is logged in, if they are I add the auth header, otherwise I don't.

I have already similar class Session manager that is created in custom Application class, so I assume that it will live until application(linux dalvik/art process) is destroyed.
So it is possible to do something like this.

```
builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                        sessionManager =(SessionProvider) getApplicationContext().getSessionManager();
                        if(sessionManager.userLoggedIn) {
                        String token = .... // getting token.
                        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        request.addHeader("Authorization",token);
                        }
                    }
```

I haven't tested this yet, but it pretends to work.
In this case redundant headers are passed to public resource requests, that don't really require them.

So maybe this can be a sort of solution not a question, but I really need some advice about any other ways (maybe not better) to solve this problem.

I will be grateful for any help.